# Python: Image to text

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, ocr

I am trying my hands on openCV and python to build a rudimentary script to read text from images.

Now I am struck on this error which says File NOT Found, problem is I am not able to understand this traceback. Which file is not there? Any library or some other problem.
It is writing thresh.png and removednoise.png.

I am working on python 3.6, if there is any compatibility issue please let me know.
If more information is required please let me know.

Help me by pointing towards a directions. Thanks in advance

Here is my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

#src_path ="D:/python'/practice"

def get_string(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    cv2.imwrite("removed_noise.png", img)
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    cv2.imwrite("thres.png", img)
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("thres.png"))

    return result


print ('------------TEXT------------')

print (get_string("imag1.png"))
```

Error message:

```
D:\python'\practice>python OCR_text.py
------------TEXT------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OCR_text.py", line 25, in <module>
    print (get_string("imag1.png"))
  File "OCR_text.py", line 18, in get_string
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("thres.png"))
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "D:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "D:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FileNotFoundError` is is raised by `subprocess`, which is trying to launch an external process. The command it's trying to launch is not found. You can see a couple lines up in the traceback it says:

```
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

To use `pytesseract` you need some other dependencies installed on your system, see this section:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract/0.1

> INSTALLATION:
>
> - Python-tesseract requires python 2.5 or later.
> - You will need the Python Imaging Library (PIL). Under Debian/Ubuntu, this is the package "python-imaging".
> - Install google tesseract-ocr from http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ . You must be able to invoke
>     the tesseract command as "tesseract". If this isn't the case, for
>     example because tesseract isn't in your PATH, you will have to change
>     the "tesseract_cmd" variable at the top of 'tesseract.py'.

Try typing `tesseract` in a command shell, if it doesn't work then you're not set up to use that package yet. Follow their install instructions.

Comment: Tesseract is installled, can it be because I have installled tesseract in C: ddirectory and I am running python and pytestesseract in D : directory

Comment: it was that issue only. I uninstalled the Tesseract from C directory and installed in D directory. Thanks bro